# Scrapy not saved data

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to create a spider that collects certain data.
There is a site with a ranking list of received students. I need everyone who was on the specialty "Computer Engineering"(комп'ютерна інженерія in Ukrainian) from all universities. 
No errors, but csv file is created empty...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class StudentSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "student"
    allowed_domains = ["https://abit-poisk.org.ua"]
    start_urls = ["https://abit-poisk.org.ua/rate2013/region/88/"]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('act=univer')), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('act=direction'),
        restrict_xpaths=(u'//td[@data-header="Напрям"]/span[contains(.,"комп’ютерна інженерія")]',)),
            callback='parse_item')
    ]

def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    links = sel.xpath('//*[@class="statement-zar"]')
    univer = sel.xpath(u'//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/a[4]/text()'.encode('utf-8')).extract_first

    for link in links:
        item = DirectoryItem()
        item['VYZ'] = univer
        item['FIO'] = link.xpath(u'td[2]/text()'.encode('utf-8')).extract()
        item['ZNO'] = link.xpath(u'td[5]/text()'.encode('utf-8')).extract()
    return items
```

I look forward to any ideas!

Comment: What does your pipeline.py file look like? Is that where you are setting up the csv file?

Comment: Ohh..I don't know about this =.= 
Thank you))

Comment: Where are you saving data? How are you running your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has a typo in td header attribute.

Try change your Xpath in rules list to `//td[@data-hedaer="Напрям"]`.

Edit: I don't found any "span" child in `td`.

This expression works:  `//td[@data-hedaer="Напрям" and contains(., "комп’ютерна інженерія")]`

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy has built-in tools for exporting to csv.

from the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html):

> For this purpose Scrapy provides a collection of Item Exporters for
>   different output formats, such as XML, CSV or JSON.

....

[CsvItemExporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter) is probably what you're looking for:

> Exports Items in CSV format to the given file-like object